# How can I fill a structure with the values of an identical structure within a function?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, extern

Okay so here's my problem:

1) I have a structure defined say like this:

```
struct minos_model
{
  int ifanis, ifdeck, npts, icb, cmb, noc;
  double tref;
  double r[MODEL_NPTS_MAX], rho[MODEL_NPTS_MAX], vpv[MODEL_NPTS_MAX],     vsv[MODEL_NPTS_MAX],
  qk[MODEL_NPTS_MAX], qmu[MODEL_NPTS_MAX], vph[MODEL_NPTS_MAX],     vsh[MODEL_NPTS_MAX], eta[MODEL_NPTS_MAX];
  char model_name[MODEL_LINE_LEN];
};
typedef struct minos_model model_t;
```

2) I have declared some structures of this form:

```
/* Declare structures */
model_t candidate_mod, current_mod, empty_mod;
```

3) I then pass them into a function declared as something like this:

```
void
perturb_model( model_t *candidate_mod, model_t *current_mod, model_t *empty_mod )
{
    candidate_mod = current_mod; // *THIS LINE*
    <various other functions and whatnot>
}
```

4) I then call the function like so:

```
perturb_model( &candidate_mod, &current_mod, &empty_mod );
// arguments passed as pointers
```

So the above is a simplified version of what I've done. I am trying (on line marked *THIS LINE* in step 3) to set candidate_mod to a different structure (current_mod), I would use a loop but one, this seems inelegant, two, sometimes the structure I am setting it equal too (current_mod) contains fewer values (than candidate_mod) and as such I am worried the excess values from the original structure (candidate_mod) would remain.

I should also mention, since perhaps it's relevant, that the function is defined in a separate c file linked in the makefile, so perhaps there is a difficulty with sharing globals.. but I think passing the pointer as an argument should solve this?

Also, it seems from my research that perhaps the use of extern might help, though I cannot figure out how after many attempts.

If someone could explain the best way to do this I would be extremely grateful!! I know how to do it trivially in my main code but the structures have to be assigned like this within the function.

Cheers.

Comment: Ignoring the massive detail and looking at the question title. Just equate them with `structB = structA` so long as you aren't just equating pointers, in which case it should be `*structB = *structA`

Answer (score 3):

Just push the value of the src into dest, don't assign pointers... But your real need is not so clear.

```
*candidate_mod = *current_mod;
```

Comment: So if I put a * in front of what is a pointer (address of a variable or structure) it will return it back to just being the variable or structure as opposed to it's address?

Comment: Also, does that mean it will change the value of the structure in my main. The thing is that I don't just want to change the value of the structure locally but globally. Will that be the case with your suggestion? Sorry, I'm trying to self teach and occasionally come a cropper.

Comment: Yes `*p` means the value of the object pointed by `p`. As you pass the address of the object created in main, then the function changes the value of the object at that address.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an address of the structure. When you say `candidate_mod = current_mod;`
you are assigning the address of `current_mod` to `candidate_mod` which is not correct. You have to dereference that structure using code like this

```
*candidate_mod = *current_mod;
```

Comment: Okay awesome, so if I put a * in front of what is a pointer (address of a variable or structure) it will return it back to just being the variable or structure as opposed to it's address?

Comment: Also, does that mean it will change the value of the structure in my main. The thing is that I don't just want to change the value of the structure locally but globally. Will that be the case with your suggestion? Sorry, I'm trying to self teach and occasionally come a cropper.

Comment: * means that you come into a address you point to and use that value. Name of the pointer is just the address of the element you point to and when you put * before name of the pointer, you use what is actually in that location you are pointing to. And yes, when you pass address like you did as a pointer argument, you can change value in the main but if you don't pass it as a pointer, you will not change any value into a main

Comment: Thank you so much!